# Paginated API request in a functional manner (Limit/Offset Based Pagination)

Tags: scala

How would I do the following logic in functional way?

1. Retrieve a List of Strings as Future from an API
2. Print the strings
3. Repeat the API Call (Step 1), but pass an offset parameter where offset is the length of the list of strings.

Is it possible to do this using a for-comprehension?

> Note: This code fails after the first iteration. I know why it doesn't (Most logic happens inside the `.map` of the Future. The while loop iterates independently of the futures content.), but i cant come up with a solution.

```scala
var offset = 0
breakable {
  while (offset < 100) {
    println(s"Loop Start. Offset = $offset")
    val eventualResponse: Future[Either[String, List[String]]] = callPaginatedApi(offset = offset)

    eventualResponse.map {
      case Right(items) =>
        println(items.mkString(", "))
        offset += items.size
      case Left(e) =>
        println("Parsing of Response failed.", e)
        break
    }.recover {
      println("Api call failed.")
      break
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Loop Start. Offset = 0
Api call failed.
String Number One, String Number Two
```

I have a working version, in which I `Await` the API call's Future, but I want to rewrite it, because I need more advanced error handling.

Comment: why don't you use recursion in place of while loop as you will have to wait for the first call to be complete or you can say the first future to be complete then only you want to execute the second call? that will also allow you to avoid break

Comment: Thanks. How would i handle errors in a recursive function using futures? If one future in the chain fails, i want to retry 3 times and then just return whatever i have fetched until the failure occured. I guess it's possible with passing an accumulator?

Comment: yes it is of course possible.